# OnsenUIのNavigatorのpushpageについて

Tags: onsen-ui

いつもお世話になっております。
OnsenUIを最新のv1.2.2にしたところ以下のようなコードのpushPageが動作しなくなってしまいました。

『 TypeError: Cannot read property 'pushPage' of undefined 』

というエラーが出てします。（ちなみにv1.2.1では動いておりました。）
pushPageのところを

『 $scope.app.navi.pushPage("page.html"); 』

とすれば動くのですが、複数のnavigatorに対して、同一の子ページを使い回したいので「app.navi」というようにnavigatorの名前を指定したくありません。
対策法をご教示ください。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

index.html (headの後半から)

```
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>  
</head>

<body ng-controller="AppController">    
<ons-navigator animation="slide" var="app.navi">
  <ons-page>
      <ons-button modifier="light" ng-click="openpage();">Push</ons-button>
  </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>

<ons-template id="page.html">
  <ons-page>
      <ons-button modifier="light" ng-click="app.navi.popPage('page.html');">Pop</ons-button>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
</body> 
</html>
```

app.js

```
var module = angular.module('app', ['onsen']);
module.controller('AppController', function($scope) { 
    $scope.openpage = function() {
        $scope.ons.navigator.pushPage("page.html");
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Onsen UIの最近のバージョンでは、`ons.navigator`という記述がサポートされなくなりました。そのため、下記のようにして`<ons-navigator>`の`var`属性を明示的に指定し、それに対して`pushPage()`メソッドを呼び出すことで解決すると思います。

HTML側:

```
<ons-navigtor var="myNavigator">
```

JavaScript側:

```
myNavigator.pushPage("page.html");
```

なお、複数のナビゲーターで同一の子ページを使用することは問題ありません。
逆に、複数のナビゲーターが同じ名前として定義することもできます。